# Error: Server Error. connect ETIMEDOUT 104.197.85.31:443

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

i am using firebase cli and i try the following

```
$ firebase init
```

the cli continue with the message :

You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:
c:\Dev\Test
are you ready to proceed ?

i type y 
and choose Hosting:Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting sites

after few second i get the error

```
Error: Server Error. connect ETIMEDOUT 104.197.85.31:443
```

what can be the problem ?

my Enviroment specification:

```
CLI Version:  3.9.1 
Platform:     win32
Node Version: v7.10.0
Time:Thu Jun 08 2017 18:03:14 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time)
```

i am useing **PSIPHONE** also as a proxy but i have also tried without **PSIPHONE** .

in both cases i get connection timeout

i have pinged 104.197.85.31 the connection is ok .

any suggestion to solve the issue ?

is it  because i am in IRAN ?

Comment: I have this problem now. Did you resolve that?!

Comment: @hamed no . i didnt try anymore.

Answer (score 6):

Just close your terminal and re-run these commands. 
`firebase login`
and now try again
`firebase deploy --only hosting`
It works for me!!!

Comment: firebase deploy --only hosting, it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why this is the first result on google but the second result had the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63832234/3393964

```
npm i -g firebase-tools
```

> Updating firebase tools worked for me. then, try again firebase deploy.
>
> if it still didn't work try clearing the firebase cache which is the .firebase file

Answer (score 2):

It's on the Firebase's end. You can check status [here](https://status.firebase.google.com/).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my work PC started blocking Firebase deploys (Even on my mobile network).

Deploying from my home PC worked just fine.

Comment: Switched to another wifi network, it worked fine.. Thanks