# Firebase cli throws Error: Server Error. connect ETIMEDOUT on every command

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I checked all the answers to this question on stack overflow. But all of them occurred due to some other reasons.

Well,
I was trying to deploy some database rules and started getting this error. And later on when i tried to do anything i realized that none of the firebase commands work and throws the same error again and again.

what all i tried : 
updates firebase tools to latest version
reset my internet connection
firebase login --reauth

but no luck.

here are the logs

```
[debug] [2018-12-25T05:41:52.644Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2018-12-25T05:41:52.648Z] Command:       C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\bin\firebase.js list
[debug] [2018-12-25T05:41:52.649Z] CLI Version:   6.2.2
[debug] [2018-12-25T05:41:52.649Z] Platform:      win32
[debug] [2018-12-25T05:41:52.649Z] Node Version:  v8.12.0
[debug] [2018-12-25T05:41:52.650Z] Time:          Tue Dec 25 2018 11:11:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
[debug] [2018-12-25T05:41:52.650Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] 
[debug] [2018-12-25T05:41:52.673Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2018-12-25T05:41:52.674Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[debug] [2018-12-25T05:41:52.677Z] > refreshing access token with scopes: ["email","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","openid"]
[debug] [2018-12-25T05:41:52.678Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token  
 <request body omitted>
[debug] [2018-12-25T05:41:53.273Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2018-12-25T05:41:53.336Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects  

[debug] [2018-12-25T05:42:14.888Z] Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.197.85.31:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1191:14)
[error] 
[error] Error: Server Error. connect ETIMEDOUT 104.197.85.31:443
```

Please suggest whatever you know about the issue.

Comment: Your output it showing CLI version 5.1.1, but the latest is 6.2.1.  Are you sure you actually installed the latest?  Yours is kind of old.

Comment: oh! sry i copied a bit old logs.leme change to the latest one

Comment: but these  logs are not so old look at the time it bears

Comment: @DougStevenson please have a look at the new logs

Comment: It looks like the CLI is having problems using the API endpoints for deployment.  You should report this to Firebase support to get more information.  I don't think there's anything Stack Overflow can do for you.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Answer (score 2):

```
npm i -g firebase-tools
```

Updating firebase tools worked for me.
then, try again `firebase deploy`.

if it still didn't work try clearing the firebase cache which is the `.firebase` file

Comment: where to find the `.firebase` file?